# Unable to boot ubuntu 12.04 even after repairing grub with boot repair

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot

i have a Dell inspiron pre-installed with ubuntu 12.04 , i installed windows 8 and then used boot repair from ubuntu 12.04 live usb to repair grub.
but system is directly booting to windows 8.

url i got is http://paste.ubuntu.com/7414543.

Please help , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe efi can be used with mbr or gpt partitioned disks.  What mode do you have your bios set to? 
Usually there is an option for uefi or legacy or something else besides uefi.  I have found that uefi likes gpt disks especially if you have as many partitions as you do.  I realize that some of your disks are logical but with gpt partitioning they won't have to be.  I am just not sure windows xp supports gpt, actually I am pretty sure it doesn't.  You should be able to do anything you need for XP in a virtual machine, however.

It looks like everything should work in theory the way you have it set up, but a lot does depend on your bios set up.  For grub to be your primary bootloader you will either have to install it to sda (not sdaX...just sda) or the better solution is what you have most likely already done which is install grub to sdb.

The **trick** there is to set your bios to boot from the second hard disk (sdb or primary slave or secondary master in your bios) After you do that, you can chainload into the windows 8 and windows xp bootloader.

If you get stuck at some point but have already been able to get grub back to a working point and can get into a version of windows.  play around with a program called EasyBCD to fix your windows related problems.

One other negative depending on your computer manufacturer about disabling uefi mode is that sometimes you lose hardware virtualization abilities.  It also can cause you problems with graphics drivers that were poorly written for uefi systems only. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In windows turn off Fast boot first.http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html.Then restart.

If it loads Ubuntu directly without grub menu,Update your Grub.
Go to terminal then type

```
sudo update-grub
```

then

```
sudo reboot
```